# Why am I getting this output when trying to pivot a table?

Tags: kdb

Trying to do a pivot and I get this.
Any suggestion what in my table can cause this.

```
©¬ time_span    value
00:00:00    (`s#`A`B`C)!9j, 23j, 9j
00:00:10    (`s#`A`B`C)!6j, 41j, 0Nj
```

Table meta :

```
©¬ c           t  f  a
time_span      v        
colWithSymbols s        
cnts           j
```

logic I am using :

```
{ dGW:asc exec distinct colWithSymbols from x;
  exec dGW#(colWithSymbols!cnts)by time_span:time_span from x
  }table
```

Comment: can you post your table please

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen before if you have hex codes hidden in your column names (and sometimes you can't see the hex codes on your display)

```
q)flip(`$("\246\251one";"two"))!(1 2;3 4)
ª⌐one two
---------
1     3
2     4
```

Try stringing and studying each of your column names/symbols to look for patterns like `"\123"` (and remove them).

It can be caused by parsing bad data from file or web app.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, is colWithSymbols a nested symbol list?

```
// creates issue
t2:([]time_span:100#00:00:00 00:00:10 00:00:20;colWithSymbols:enlist each 100?`1;cnts:100?100)

dGW2:asc exec distinct colWithSymbols from t2

exec dGW2#(colWithSymbols!cnts) by time_span:time_span from t2
time_span|                                                                   ..
---------| ------------------------------------------------------------------..
00:00:00 | `s#(,`a;,`b;,`c;,`d;,`e;,`f;,`g;,`h;,`i;,`j;,`k;,`l;,`m;,`n;,`o;,`..
00:00:10 | `s#(,`a;,`b;,`c;,`d;,`e;,`f;,`g;,`h;,`i;,`j;,`k;,`l;,`m;,`n;,`o;,`..
00:00:20 | `s#(,`a;,`b;,`c;,`d;,`e;,`f;,`g;,`h;,`i;,`j;,`k;,`l;,`m;,`n;,`o;,`..
```

Solve with ungroup:

```
dGW3:asc exec distinct colWithSymbols from ungroup t2

exec dGW3#(colWithSymbols!cnts) by time_span:time_span from ungroup t2

time_span| a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p
---------| -----------------------------------------------
00:00:00 |    62 76 90 25 84 17 97    2     0     73 51 30
00:00:10 | 89 25 37    14 77 42 15 63    7  43 81 81
00:00:20 | 3  49 29 6  87 14 62 72 63 68 75 64 28 28 4  31
```